# Jenkins multibranch pipeline job CHANGE_ID not set

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request, multibranch-pipeline

I have setup a job with Jenkins with MultiBranch pipeline. 
Github is the SCM and is configured, with a webhook to fire a build on a PR commit. (Existing or new PR).

The build is triggered, all goes fine [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOl2.png), however the CHANGE_ID is not set (null). We need the CHANGE_ID to pass on to Sonar.

I am struggling to understand, in which cases this parameter is set, and why it's null in our case.

Please consider this question from a Jenkins Multibranch perspective. 
Our (git related) plugin installations is here [2] .

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOl2.png) logging from Jenkins.

```
    [Mon Jun 26 11:32:48 CEST 2017] Received Push event to branch BE-7394 in repository ServiceHouse/api UPDATED event from 172.18.0.1 ⇒ http://jenkins2.servicehouse.nl:8080/github-webhook/ with timestamp Mon Jun 26 11:32:43 CEST 2017
11:32:50 Connecting to https://api.github.com using shojenkinsuser/******
Looking up ServiceHouse/api

11:32:50 Connecting to https://api.github.com using shojenkinsuser/******
Looking up ServiceHouse/api

  Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch BE-7394
  Getting remote branches...

    Checking branch BE-7394
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: BE-7394 (01293286b6ee34056d8c92e21a6d39d18e537a81 → 35c16ef01bba5d27dd040a881cd3734fef271fd7)
Scheduled build for branch: BE-7394

  0 branches were processed (query completed)

Done examining ServiceHouse/api
```

[2] Git related Installed plugins: 
[image: git related plugins]

Answer (score 0):

This variable sutup in the branch-api-plugin ([setup source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/28be8058a6faea90f0549b80cce2c24714f69ea4/src/main/java/jenkins/branch/BranchNameContributor.java)) and we have it working for pull requests or change requests.

For branches of the form -, it is not filled.

I can advise you to use:

```
BUILD_NUMBER
The current build number, such as "153"

BUILD_ID
The current build ID, identical to BUILD_NUMBER for builds created in 
1.597+, but a YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss timestamp for older builds
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'For branches of the form -, it is not filled.' ?

Comment: Ohh. For branches not match the mask PR-<id> or CR-<id> CHANGE_ID not filled